# How to limit max value in textfield with handler javafx

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

How to limit max value in textfield with handler javafx?

In my textfield, I want to the user don't enter a value > 127?

How to do that with a Handler?

I have already limit the textfield to numeric values (with regex)

Comment: In the code where you limit the input (I assume it's an EventHandler or an ActionListener) you could try casting the input to an int and check the range that way. Make sure to check for negative numbers too!

Comment: No problem, can you post some more complete code snippets in your question? Code formatting helps :) I may not be able to post an answer until later this evening when I'm off work

Comment: Ok, how to formatting the code in the answers ?
Ok thanks :)

Comment: you can indent all the lines of code by four spaces, or you can select a block of code and click the button that looks like this { } in the little toolbar at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an event handler, which allows the user to input invalid values and then either ignores them or fixes them, consider subclassing `TextField` to allow only valid input.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.IndexRange;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RestrictedTextFieldExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TextField restrictedTextField = new TextField() {

            private final Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}");
            @Override
            public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
                if (valid(start, end, text)) {
                    super.replaceText(start, end, text);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void replaceSelection(String text) {
                IndexRange selectionRange = getSelection();
                if (valid(selectionRange.getStart(), selectionRange.getEnd(), text)) {
                    super.replaceSelection(text);
                }
            }


            private boolean valid(int start, int end, String text) {
                String attemptedText = 
                        getText().substring(0, start)
                        + text
                        + getText().substring(end);
                if (attemptedText.length() == 0) {
                    return true ;
                }
                if (numberPattern.matcher(attemptedText).matches()) {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(attemptedText);
                    if (value >= 0 && value <= 127) {
                        return true ;
                    }
                }
                return false ;
            }
        };

        IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        value.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(new Callable<Integer>(){

            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                String text = restrictedTextField.getText();
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    return 0 ;
                } else {
                    return Integer.parseInt(text);
                }
            }

        }, restrictedTextField.textProperty()));

        value.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.printf("Value changed from %d to %d%n", oldValue.intValue(), newValue.intValue());
            }

        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.getChildren().add(restrictedTextField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This follows the example from Richard Bair in the [fx experience blog](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/restricting-input-on-a-textfield/)

Comment: I don't understand the part with the bind.
Can you explain me please ?

Answer (score 0):

[If this example documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm) is anything to go by, you should have access to the object that generates the KeyEvent (someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

```
   String str= new String(); 
   int iCharacter; 
   public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) { 
      str+=keyEvent.getCharacter(); 


      //should be able to get the object like txtField_fxid.getText();
      String input = fxid.getString();  
      int value = Integer.parseInt( input );
      if( value > 0 && value < 127 ){
          //   do stuff
      }
   }
```

I will update this when I get home today.

Comment: For what reason do you use "fxid.getString()" ?

Comment: Eumh... Same issue, because, if the user use DELETE key, the string doesn't change and the value of "value" is corrupt

Comment: there is a way to account for a delete in JavaFX. Simply remove the trailing character while checking to make sure you don't have an empty string.

Comment: suppose I input "123". I then delete the 2. What will happen if you print 'str'? You may not be handling deletes correctly, if at all. Please post more code in your question above so we have more to work with (all actionlisteners or eventhandlers)

Comment: Thanks! What does it print if you input "123" and then delete the 2?

Comment: All these are reasons not to try to use an event handler to manage this, and to use the solution I posted using the subclass of `TextField`. If you try to use the key handler, what if the user pastes in content using ctrl-V? And what if they use the mouse to paste in content???

Answer (score 0):

This method let TextField to finish all processing (copy/paste/undo safe).
Do not requares to make extending class.
And allow you to deside what to do with new text after every change
(to push it to logic, or turn back to previous value, or even to modify it).

```
  // fired by every text property change
textField.textProperty().addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // Your validation rules, anything you like
      // (! note 1 !) make sure that empty string (newValue.equals("")) 
      //   or initial text is always valid
      //   to prevent inifinity cycle
    // do whatever you want with newValue

    // If newValue is not valid for your rules
    ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
      // (! note 2 !) do not bind textProperty (textProperty().bind(someProperty))
      //   to anything in your code.  TextProperty implementation
      //   of StringProperty in TextFieldControl
      //   will throw RuntimeException in this case on setValue(string) call.
      //   Or catch and handle this exception.

    // If you want to change something in text
      // When it is valid for you with some changes that can be automated.
      // For example change it to upper case
    ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(newValue.toUpperCase());
  }
);
```

For your case just add this logic inside. Works perfectly.

```
   if (newValue.equals("")) return; 
   try {
     Integer i = Integer.valueOf(newValue);
     if (i >= 0 && i <= 127) {
       // do what you want with this i
     } else {
       ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
     }
   } catch (Exception e) {
     ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
   }
```